# How to show the number for each row in a column in the cxgrid

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I have found a kind of an answer here :

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2079

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T357085

But I need the code in Delphi. I understand I need to have an unbound column but dont know the right code. So any help would be nice.

Comment: You've not provided any information here, you've linked an external site, and you've not asked a question.We should not have to leave this site to find out what you're asking. We're also not a code-translation service. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: Question is pretty clear I think . The answers on those sites refer to another programing languages and I need that code in Delphi (pascal).

Comment: Question is not clear. There's no information here, we do not go somewhere else to figure out what you're asking, and we're not a language conversion service for porting code from one language to another. See the link I provided already and try again. Explain the problem you're having, post the code, your efforts to convert it, and ask a specific question and perhaps we can help.

Comment: The links you posted are for the .NET grid, not the VCL one. Otherwise there *would* be Delphi code. I'm sure you'll find the solution on support center. Set the filter to VCL or ExpressQuantumGrid Suite and search again.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the answer here on devexpress support center:

[TcxGrid Row Number](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A767)

It explains how to add row numbers in an unbound grid column.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the section "Provide context for links".

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).